# PHP Websocket not listening for remote connection

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am trying to write up a realtime chat app using Websockets. I tried to set up a Websockets server using two different PHP implementations. (https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket and http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/) I ran the server using xampp shell and both worked fine when I connected from the same computer. However, when I tried to connect using another computer in the same LAN, the server didn't even receive a handshake request.

Is that due to the same-origin policy? Is there a workaround?

I am using xampp 1.7.1 and PHP 5.3.8 if that matters

Comment: Probably firewall. Turn it off or add an exception for the PHP binary to the incoming packet filter.

Comment: Just to be sure : [was the other browser websocket compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) ?

Comment: Both test performed using Chrome 19, and I turned off the firewall but still no luck

Comment: Please provide the connecting request and the exact error from Chrome's console.